# Merging several measures of score's part in LilyPond

Tags: notation, lilypond

I'm wondering if is it possible to notate a score like on the picture below in LilyPond. The problem here is that the third measure of the topmost part (which is flute, actually) should be stretched across several measures of the piano part. This measure has no actual time signature, and it is played in a free manner.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is sort of a skeleton to work with. All the involved features are explained (including examples) in the notation manual anyway.

```
\new Score \with { \remove "Timing_translator"
                   \remove "Default_bar_line_engraver"
                   \numericTimeSignature
                 }
\new StaffGroup
<<
  \new Staff \with { \consists "Timing_translator"
                     \consists "Default_bar_line_engraver"
                   }
  {
    \time 3/4 R2.*2 \cadenzaOn
    \scaleDurations 2/1
    { a'4( gis'4~ \tuplet 3/2 4 { gis'8[ c'' b'] f''[ e'' g''] } b''2)
      as'4( es'~ es'8[ es''] as''[ c'''] es'''4)
    }
  }
  \new PianoStaff \with { \consists "Timing_translator"
                          \consists "Default_bar_line_engraver" }
  <<
    \new Staff \relative { \time 3/4 c''4 c c c c c
                           \time 2/4 c c
                           \time 4/4 c c c c
                           \time 2/4 c c
                           \time 4/4 \repeat unfold 16 c }
    \new Staff { \clef "bass" \repeat unfold 30 c }
  >>
>>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you a lot. It is what I needed. Almost. Can I synchronize measures from both parts back after the stretched measure ends? By the way, I don't quite understand what's wrong with the tags (agreed about the title though :) ), but I'll try to fix it up.

Comment: Well, I think I get it. I just need to turn cadenza off.

Comment: I found yet another option to do the same thing, which IMHO does the job just a little more clearly. All you need to do is to create a measure with the command "\set Timing.measureLength = #(ly:make-moment 12/4)" and resize/scale it by "\scaleDurations 24/12".